# CSS Table Cell doesn't become full width

Tags: html, css, css-tables

I want to create a table design in pure CSS. I gave different classes to `<span>` tags. They define the width of the cell. Now I want to insert a row with a single column (width 100%). But the `<span>` tags don't become 100%.

Please see the example:

```
<div class="table">
    <span class="row head">
        <span class="cell w40">
            Title
        </span>
        <span class="cell w20">
            Title
        </span>
        <span class="cell w20">
            Title
        </span>
        <span class="cell w20">
            Title
        </span>
    </span>
    <span class="row single"><span class="cell center">Full width?</span></span>
</div>
```

The CSS:

```
.table {
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 800px;
}
.table .row {
  display: table-row;
  width: 100%;
}
.table .row.head {
  font-weight: 600;
  background: #d4291f;
  color: white;
}
.table .row.head:hover .cell {
  background: #d4291f;
}
.table .row:hover .cell {
  background: #eeeeee;
}
.table .row.single .cell {
  width: 100%;
  display: block;
}
.table .cell {
  padding: 8px 8px;
  vertical-align: top;
  display: table-cell;
}
.table .cell.w40 {
  width: 40%;
}
.table .cell.w20 {
  width: 20%;
}
.table .cell.center {
  text-align: center;
}
```

Do you have any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some research I believe this is the way to make it work. [Demo Link](http://plnkr.co/edit/S5fijL6Al7whH4ULGlOP?p=preview)

```
<div class="table">
<span class="row head">
    <span class="cell w40">
        Title
    </span>
    <span class="cell w20">
        Title
    </span>
    <span class="cell w20">
        Title
    </span>
    <span class="cell w20">
        Title
    </span>
</span>
</div>
<div class="table">
  <span class="row single">
    <span class="cell center">
      Full width?
    </span>
  </span>
</div>
```

and the .css changes only a bit, I've removed the 'width: 100%;'

```
.table .row.single .cell {
  display: block;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that was it! Difficult to find.

Answer (score 0):

Because span is displayed inline by default. Try to change you span class to **display:inline-block**